# TFS- 2013 auto build Cloaked folder is giving not found issue

Tags: tfs

Status        Source Control Folder                                                                      Build Agent Folder

Active

```
$/project111/Dev/Source/Product111_UI                                               
$(SourceDir)
```

Cloaked

```
 $/project111/Dev/Source/Product111_UI/kendoUI/Modules/Sample
```

above are the my work space settings from build configuration. 
It is giving below issue while copying build.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets (182): Could not copy the file "Modules\Sample\AliasConfig\AliasConfig.html" because it was not found.

do I missed any configurations still,  please help me out in this. if any 
solution.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a reference to the output of that .html fil le somewhere in your build logic. Cloaking the folder means that it is not there so the error is correct.

You need to find where you have a reference to that .html file in your build logic.